# How to solve 5 * 5 Cube in efficient easy way

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

There is 5*5 cube puzzle named Happy cube Problem where for given mat , need to make a cube .
http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/cube_its.htm#top

Its like,  6 blue mats are given-
[image]

From the following mats, Need to derive a Cube -
[image]

These way it has 3 more solutions.
So like first cub

For such problem, the easiest approach I could imagine was Recursion based where for each cube, I have 6 position , and for each position I will try check all other mate and which fit, I will go again recursively to solve the same. Like finding all permutations of each of the cube and then find which fits the best.So Dynamic Programming approach.

But I am making loads of mistake in recursion , so is there any better easy approach which I can use to solve the same?

I made matrix out of each mat or diagram provided, then I rotated them in each 90 clock-wise 4 times and anticlock wise times . I flip the array and did the same, now for each of the above iteration I will have to repeat the step for other cube, so again recursion .

```
 0 0 1 0 1
 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 1 1 0
 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 0 1 1
-------------
 0 1 0 1 0
 1 1 1 1 0
 0 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 0
 1 1 0 1 1
-------------
 1 1 0 1 1
 0 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 0
 0 1 1 1 1
 0 1 0 1 0
-------------
 1 0 1 0 0
 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 1 1 0
 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 0 1 0
-------------

1st - block is the Diagram
2nd - rotate clock wise
3rd - rotate anti clockwise
4th - flip
```

Still struggling to sort out the logic .

Comment: well, either my brain just completely f*cked up, or the example isn't even a solution. 4 and 5 don't fit together as far as I can see. same for 4 and 6

Comment: I followed the link http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/cube_its.htm#top which stated that it has 3 more solution 4'/5'16/2/3, 2/4'15/6'/3', 4'/612/5'/3

Comment: pls help, my brain is fighting itself. i can't decide whether the solution is correct or not

Comment: finally. I found the solution. the solution works by letting some of the edges stick out of the cube. well, good luck with implementing that

Comment: even we just reject the solution , what must be the approach to sort out the problem programmatically,

Comment: damnit, it starts again, the above mentioned approach only works for 4 and 5, not 4 and 6. i have absolutely no clue, how these pieces should fit together

Comment: i'd love to see a solution for this problem. Though i've absolutely no idea how to approach this. Or even how to solve the cube itself

Comment: A couple of thoughts... 
(1) The problem is three dimensional, in that the mat has a thickness equal to one of the smaller squares, so it is possible to construct a cube with no pieces missing or sticking out.
(2) I don't believe the solution above is valid: the problem is that the notation given does not say which orientation a piece is in. I think if you rotate piece 6 90 degrees anti-clockwise you will have a valid solution, which will still match the "4'/5'16/2/3" pattern.

Comment: Oh cool, we had one of these at primary school.

Comment: This might be more fun with a 3D printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe this, but I actually wrote a set of scripts back in 2009 to brute-force solutions to this exact problem, for the simple cube case. I just put the code on Github: https://github.com/niklasb/3d-puzzle

Unfortunately the documentation is in German because that's the only language my team understood, but source code comments are in English. In particular, check out the file `puzzle_lib.rb`.

The approach is indeed just a straightforward backtracking algorithm, which I think is the way to go. I can't really say it's *easy* though, as far as I remember the 3-d aspect is a bit challenging. I implemented one optimization: Find all symmetries beforehand and only try each unique orientation of a piece. The idea is that the more *characteristic* the pieces are, the less options for placing pieces exist, so we can prune early. In the case of many symmetries, there might be lots of possibilities and we want to inspect only the ones that are unique up to symmetry.

Basically the algorithm works as follows: First, assign a fixed order to the sides of the cube, let's number them 0 to 5 for example. Then execute the following algorithm:

```
def check_slots():
    for each edge e:
        if slot adjacent to e are filled:
            if the 1-0 patterns of the piece edges (excluding the corners)
                   have XOR != 0:
                return false
            if the corners are not "consistent":
                return false
    return true

def backtrack(slot_idx, pieces_left):
    if slot_idx == 6:
        # finished, we found a solution, output it or whatever
        return
    for each piece in pieces_left:
        for each orientation o of piece:
            fill slot slot_idx with piece in orientation o
            if check_slots():
                backtrack(slot_idx + 1, pieces_left \ {piece})
            empty slot slot_idx
```

The corner consistency is a bit tricky: Either the corner must be filled by exactly one of the adjacent pieces or it must be accessible from a yet unfilled slot, i.e. not cut off by the already assigned pieces.

Of course you can ignore to drop some or all of the consistency checks and only check in the end, seeing as there are only 8^6 * 6! possible configurations overall. If you have more than 6 pieces, it becomes more important to prune early.

Comment: thanks for that , is the array orientation is the collection of all the rotations of any cube ?

Comment: @Marek I can't say I know what I mean. Are you referring to the code or the pseudocode in my answer?

Comment: yeah I am talking about this piece of code fill slot slot_idx with piece in orientation o

Comment: @Marek No it's not an array. I'm using natural language in that pseudocode for simplicity. What I mean is,  for every piece, for every orientation of the piece, try putting it in the slot

Comment: thanks for that , I believe I got something to write now