# How to find all combinations of multiple 2D arrays(matrix) , rotation allowed

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have 3 2d Arrays(matrix) with 0 and 1-

For each array, I will rotate 4 times clock-wise , 4 times anti clock-wise and flip the array and repeat the above and for each iteration I will repeat the steps for other array and so on to combine the array to build a symmetry or kind of Rubik's cube but with 5 elements each side. It means if I like to add 2 arrays , it means 1 of Array 1 must be fit with 0 of Array 2.
Following kind of structure-

[image]

Following is my 3 arrays

```
 0 0 1 0 1
 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 1 1 0
 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 0 1 1
-------------
 0 1 0 1 0
 0 1 1 1 0
 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 1 1 0
 0 0 1 0 0
-------------
 1 0 1 0 0
 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 1 1 0
 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 0 1 0
-------------
```

This problem is evolved from the problem I asked [How to solve 5 * 5 Cube in efficient easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392524/how-to-solve-5-5-cube-in-efficient-easy-way).

```
Consider my rotate methods are as follows -
rotateLeft()
rotateRight()
flipSide()

for (firstArray){
  element = single.rotateLeft();
  for(secondArray){
     element2 = single.rotateLeft();
    if(element.combine(element2){
     for(thirdArray){

     }
}
   }
}
```

Currently I have fixed 3 arrays , but how exactly and efficiently I must solve this problem.